# Recursive Function Type Defintions

Tags: go

I'm a little confused at what is going on here with this recursive type definition:

```
type Func func() (int, int, Func)
```

Note: I know how to use it via trial and error but I'm very uncertain as to what it(the recursive type definition) is.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fib(x int) int {
    if x == 0 {
        return 0
    } else if x == 1 {
        return 1
    } else {
        return fib(x-1) + fib(x-2)
    }
}

type Func func() (int, int, Func)

func get_fib(x int) (int, int, Func) {
    return x, fib(x), func() (int, int, Func) { return get_fib(x + 1) }
}

func main() {
    d, n, f := get_fib(10)
    d1, n1, f1 := f()
    d2, n2, _ := f1()
    fmt.Println(d, n)
    fmt.Println(d1, n1)
    fmt.Println(d2, n2)
}
```

Can anyone shed some light on what's created in the above recursive type definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

type `Func func() (int, int, Func)` is just a function type whose type name is `Func`. You can treat it as an anonymous function with zero parameter and 3 return value (and the last return value is also a Func type).

When assign some variable to this function type (`Func`), the variable will be the name of this function. Then you can call the function with variable-name as the fuction name.

In the code above, `d, n, f := get_fib(10)`, d get `10`, n get `fib(10)`, fu get `func() (int, int, Func) { return get_fib(11) }`. Then you can call `f()` to which will return  the result of `get_fib(11)` directly.

==============================================================

Why the recursive type is needed to create this functionality:

Just my thoughts: get_fib function wants to return three results: x, the input of fib function (type int), the result of fib function (type int), a function to return the function of get_fib(x+1) (type func, not Func now). (So get_fib is also a kind of recursive because it uses get_fib in its return.) As the function (type func, not Func now) returns a get_fib(x+1) whose return types are the same as those of get_fib(x). So function's return types should be `int, int, func` (func is the third result in get_fib's return which is the function definition itself).  So a recursive function type is needed.

In a brief:

- Output of get_fib is (int, int, customfunc)
- Output of customfunc is (get_fib) which is (int, int, customfunc) **again**.
- So the customfunc's output is (int, int, customfunc) which is a recursive function type

Comment: Thanks for the answer Zhor but I think you gave me a usage example and not why the recursive type is needed to create this functionality. Its my understanding that you have to create this recursive type to generate this functionality and that's what I'm looking for.. What this type achieves and how... Maybe I'm over-complicating  the recursive type.

Comment: I added my thoughts to my answer. Not sure if these addresses your question.

Comment: So the recursive type is needed to put a  name on the recursion?

Comment: I am not sure what is "name on the recursion" you refer to. My understanding of recursive type definition in golang is: define a type with some name and use the same name in the type definition.  For example, type RecurStuct struct{field *RecurStuct}. The field recursively defined has to be some pointer value.

Comment: In your example(example in your comment) you named a type which is used in/for the recursive data structure. Without that explicit naming of the type, could you define a recursive data structure?

Comment: No, I can't. I think a explicit type name is needed to reference within the type definition to create a recursive data structure.  The recursive function type definition in your post "type Func func() (int, int, Func)" also has a explicit type named "Func".